# Правильно ли с Redux хранить весь store в Provider?

Tags: reactjs, redux

В doce реакт говорят, что в context нужно хранить только глобальные вещи, а c Redux-oм  мы весь store в Provider кидаем. Разве так правильно??? В doce react  нам говорят, что так нельзя. Если я что-то не понимаю - объясните.

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название, пожалуйста

Comment: Всё ещё плохо. В названии вопроса должна быть отражена его суть, например "Правильно ли с Redux хранить весь store в Provider?"